# jQuery Data Format in dd-mmm-yyyy check with regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, date-format

I need to check the data format in `dd-mm-yyyy` format.

I'm using the following:

```
if (ValidateDate() == false) {
   alert("Wrong Date Format");
return false;
}

function ValidateDate() {

    var dtValue = $('#txtEnteredStartDate').val();
    var dtRegex = new RegExp("^(([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[1-9]|3[0-1])[-]([JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JULY|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC])[-](d{4}))$");
    return dtRegex.test(dtValue);
}
```

But when I enter `dd-mmm-yyyy` in the field, for example `19-Nov-2015`, I'm getting the error `Wrong date format`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @gene Is `'#txtEnteredStartDate'` an `input type="date"` element ?

Comment: Using just a regex is not sufficient, it will not validate for example number of days in different months. For example 31-Feb-2015 would pass, but no such date exists. You need to parse your date-string, create a Date object from it and compare if it is still the original date (e.g. 31 Feb would become 3 Mar - a different date)

Comment: With the regex you can validate the format, not the value, that's what I wanted to express

Comment: I'm using the calendar control and provide the logic to disallow entering the data into the input field except of "-". Also, I only allow to delete data by pressing backslash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PhilVarg's** regex is correct, though applying it in `RegExp` you need to `\\` the `d`.

Also, you can re-factor the `([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[1-9]|3[0-1])` down to `([0]?[1-9]|[1-2]\\d|3[0-1])` which means an option 0 followed by 1 to 9 or 1,2 followed by a number, or 3 followed by 0 or 1.

1 Last thing, theres no need for `[]` around the `-`, and to pass `i` (ignore case) RegExp accepts it as a second argument.

Working Example:-

```js
function ValidateDate() {
  var dtValue = $('#txtEnteredStartDate').val();
  var dtRegex = new RegExp("^([0]?[1-9]|[1-2]\\d|3[0-1])-(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JULY|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)-[1-2]\\d{3}$", 'i');
  return dtRegex.test(dtValue);
}

$('.check').click(function() {
  if (ValidateDate() == false) {
    $('.result').html("Wrong Date Format");
  } else {
    $('.result').html("Right Date Format");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtEnteredStartDate" value="19-Nov-2015" />
<input type="button" class="check" value="check" />
<span class="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a couple of errors in your regex

first, `(d{4})` needs to be `(\d{4})` because its currently looking for 4 `d`'s and needs to look for four digits

second, the brackets around the months are causing it to fail as it looking for a **single character** `J`, `A`, or `N` OR `F`, `E`, `B` etc

and last, it needs to be a case insensitive regex

the following regex should work:

```
/^(([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[1-9]|3[0-1])[-](JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JULY|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)[-](\d{4}))$/i
```

as seen [here](http://scriptular.com/#%5E((%5B1-9%5D%7C0%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5B0-9%5D%7C2%5B1-9%5D%7C3%5B0-1%5D)%5B-%5D(JAN%7CFEB%7CMAR%7CAPR%7CMAY%7CJUN%7CJULY%7CAUG%7CSEP%7COCT%7CNOV%7CDEC)%5B-%5D(%5Cd%7B4%7D))%24%7C%7C%7C%7Ci%7C%7C%7C%7C%5B%2219-Nov-2015%22%5D)

Comment: That's is really strange, but it does not work

Comment: can you console log dtValue and dtRegex and ensure they are the desired inputs

Answer (score 0):

I found another way that worked for me:

```
function ValidateDate(dtValue) {

    var dtRegex = new RegExp(/^\d\d?-\w\w\w-\d\d\d\d/);
    return dtRegex.test(dtValue);
}
```

Thank you all for your suggestions

Comment: be carefully with that as it would match `00-___-0000`. `\w` matchs letters, numbers and underscore.

Comment: In my case, I'm using the calendar control and provide the logic to disallow entering the data into the input field except of "-". Also, I only allow to delete data by pressing backslash

Comment: @gene, You're missing a `$` at the end.  @BG101, How did you guess my password?